# Convert date format without timezone - Google app script (Javascript), Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, line, bots

I'm working on integration between Google spreadsheet and LINE Message API (BOT) where Google app script is back-end.

I get the date-format cell from Google spreadsheet and send to LINE bot but the message reply showed different thing. 
in a cell of **Google Spreadsheet**

> **1/5/2020**

In Google app script, I first coded it

```
var colb =  ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(i+3, 2).getValue();
```

but LINE message, it sends format included timezone as default

> **Sun Jan 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)**

So I coded it

```
var colb =  Utilities.formatDate(ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(i+3, 2).getValue(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YY");
```

This one is works but it's not working when cell is empty which is I have no clue why. So someone please help me with this. Thank in advance

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean with "not working" and what you would expect as an outcome? The first parameter of the `formatDate` function is expected to be a date. What would you expect your script to do when you get an empty input? Or something else than a date (string, number,...)?

Comment: Apologies about that, okay the outcome I expect is the same value as in the cell of the spreadsheet. If cell has value 1/5/2020, the outcome should be **1/5/2020** as well or if possible, I want it **Sun Jan 05 2020**. If the cell is emply, i expect blank **" "**

Answer (score 0):

If cell is empty and you want to use Utilities.formatDate I would do like this:

```
var colb =  " " || Utilities.formatDate(ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(i+3, 2).getValue(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YY");
```

So in case there is no value in cell just assign default value " "

Answer (score 0):

If you need `colb` to contain the original value (including empty) when the date conversion doesn't work, you can do this:

```
var value = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(i+3, 2).getValue();
var colb = (typeof value == "object" && value instanceof Date) ? Utilities.formatDate(value, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/YY") : value;
```